# Renombrar fotos calculando la edad de la persona

Tags: javascript

Estoy queriendo escribir un código para un botón de un explorador de archivos que me permita, al seleccionar una foto y presionar dicho botón, renombrar la foto con la edad de la persona.

Ejemplo: `Esther.jpg` >>> `Esther (1a 3m 8d).jpg`

Para el cálculo de edad utilizo la edad de la persona, especificada de forma fija en el código; y la fecha de captura de la foto, obtenida desde sus metadatos.

Pero la edad que se está calculando es incorrecta. Por ejemplo, en el script está especificada como fecha de nacimiento: 07-08-2023, si selecciono una foto tirada al otro día (fecha de captura: 08-08-2023) (1 día de diferencia), lo correcto es que el resultado fuera:

`Esther (0a 0m 1d).jpg` y está siendo `Esther (2a 10m 29d).jpg`, casi 3 años de diferencia.

```js
function OnGetNewName(getNewNameData) {
    var fechaNacimiento = new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 08, 07, 00, 00, 00));

    var item = getNewNameData.item;
    var metadata = item.metadata;

    if (metadata && metadata.image && metadata.image.datetaken) {
        var fechaCaptura = new Date(metadata.image.datetaken);
        var diff = fechaCaptura - fechaNacimiento;

        var años = Math.floor(diff / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var meses = Math.floor((diff % (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (30.44 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var días = Math.floor((diff % (30.44 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

        var edad = "(" + años + "a " + meses + "m " + días + "d)";

        var result = item.name_stem + " " + edad + item.ext;
        return result;
    } else {
        return item.name;
    }
}
```

**Objeto Fecha**
https://www.gpsoft.com.au/help/opus12/index.html#!Documents/Scripting/Date.htm

Comment: Hola @Marce Puente, mi intención sería, por ejemplo, que una foto con nombre "Ester.jpg" se convierta en "Ester (1a 3m 5d).jpg". No me encontraría nunca con ese problema que me ilustras pues nunca tendré 2 fotos con el mismo nombre, unas veces tendré "Ester con su mascota", otras veces "Ester durmiendo" y así por el estilo. Yo hago este cálculo de edad manualmente en Excel pero es un poco incómodo porque son muchas fotos. Muchas gracias por el interés en ayudarme!

Comment: Edité mi comentario anterior porque no había entendido bien la situación que me plateabas, disculpa. Realmente nunca tendré 2 fotos con el mismo nombre, siempre tendré una breve descripción que las hará diferentes, por ejemplo, unas veces tendré **"Ester con su mascota.jpg"**, otras veces **"Ester durmiendo.jpg"** y así por el estilo.

Comment: Tengo una duda, como estas haciendo para incluir el botón en el explorador de archivos y que este botón ejecute código jscript ???? Estás usando software adicional?

Comment: El propio explorador de archivos (Directory Opus) permite crear diferentes tipos de botones (botones simples, botones de 3 funciones, botones Menús, etc.) y cada botón permite seleccionar el tipo de función a ejecutar con él (funciones estándar, funciones por lotes MS-DOS y funciones script (JScript y VBScript)

Comment: Veo que el segundo fragmento de código tiene formato `xml` pero no logro identificar el *ambiente/framework/programa* en el cual estas trabajando, podría decir a mi criterio que es una pagina web, interfaz u otra cosa relacionada, es obvio que una de las cosas principales es **JavaScript** pero no asimilo lo demás.

Comment: Hola @user327285, cierto, el formato del botón es en ```xml```, y se trata de un botón de un explorador de archivo que acepta funciones de diferentes tipos como funciones estándar, funciones por lotes MS-DOS y funciones script (JScript y VBScript)

Comment: No le preste mucha atención a mí primer código que no tiene ningún fundamento, fue solo una idea mía, pues no sé prácticamente nada de programación.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 es localhost... Los demás no pueden verlo, solo vos. ¿Cuál es la finalidad de tener esos enlaces en la pregunta?

Comment: Hola @padaleiana, no sabía de ese detalle, ya lo corregí, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ok, estoy yendo

Comment: Oi @MarcePuente un día de estos, si puedes, échale un vistazo al código actual, él ahora está funcionando, le dí formato a la fecha de nacimiento, pero la edad que está calculando está incorrecta, intenta descubrir la causa del error, gracias

Comment: Cerre tu pregunta, porque con 36!!! ediciones, para mi, tenes una confusion total. Una pregunta, una respuesta. Tenes 2 respuestas, que tienen 5 dias... No es una pregunta, la cambio, otra pregunta, la cambio, hasta que alguien resuelve completamente lo que vos queres.

Comment: Oi @gbianchi, si he editado la pregunta varias veces ha sido corrigiendo pequeños detalles, como signos de puntuación y cosas así, la esencia de la pregunta ha sido siempre la misma, de todas formas, fica a vontade!

Comment: No es necesario que me mientas.. todas las ediciones son publicas, y mas para mi que soy moderador electo. Agregaste codigo, sacaste codigo, agregaste links, sacas cosas. O sea.. si tenes 3 respuestas, ninguna responde tu pregunta??? cual es el problema que tenes con las respuestas??? cual es la necesidad de seguir editando la pregunta???

Comment: y no.. la esencia de la pregunta no es la misma.. en la primera pedias un script que hiciera este cambio en el nombre del archivo.. en la actualidad, dice "Pero la edad que se está calculando es incorrecta".. o sea, ya es otra pregunta!!!!!

Comment: Todo bien, continua con la pregunta cerrada, pero ojalá y la misma voluntad que tienes para censurar, la tuvieras para ayudar, no es la primera vez que me cruzo contigo y nunca das una respuesta de ayuda, mucha suerte!

Comment: Llegué a entrar en el chat pero no supe contestarte, no encontré ningún botón, ni campo de texto, pero te respondí por aquí, gracias mil por todo

Comment: No es censura, es enseñar cómo funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 6):

```
// Fecha de nacimiento fija en el formato "AAAA-MM-DD"
var fecha_nacimiento = "2020-05-14";

// Función para obtener la diferencia en años entre dos fechas
function calcularEdad(fechaNacimiento, fechaCaptura) {
  var fechaNac = new Date(fechaNacimiento);
  var fechaCap = new Date(fechaCaptura);

  var edad = fechaCap.getFullYear() - fechaNac.getFullYear();
  var m = fechaCap.getMonth() - fechaNac.getMonth();

  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && fechaCap.getDate() < fechaNac.getDate())) {
    edad--;
  }

  return edad;
}

// Función para formatear la edad en el formato "añosa mesmeses ddías"
function formatearEdad(edad) {
  var anios = Math.floor(edad);
  var meses = Math.floor((edad - anios) * 12);
  var dias = Math.floor(((edad - anios) * 12 - meses) * 30);

  return anios + "a " + meses + "m " + dias + "d";
}

// Función para renombrar las fotografías con la edad de la persona
function renombrarFotos(fechaNacimiento) {
  var objShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
  var objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Seleccione la carpeta con las fotografías", 0);

  if (objFolder != null) {
    var folderPath = objFolder.Items().Item().Path;
    var folderItems = objFolder.Items();

    for (var i = 0; i < folderItems.Count; i++) {
      var item = folderItems.Item(i);
      var filePath = folderPath + "\\" + item.Name;
      var fechaCaptura = new Date(item.ModifyDate);

      var edad = calcularEdad(fechaNacimiento, fechaCaptura);
      var nuevoNombre = item.Name.replace(/\..+$/, "") + " (" + formatearEdad(edad) + ")" + item.ExtendedProperty("Type");

      // Renombrar el archivo
      objShell.NameSpace(folderPath).MoveHere(filePath, 0x14);

      var newFilePath = folderPath + "\\" + nuevoNombre;
      objShell.NameSpace(folderPath).MoveHere(newFilePath, 0x14);
    }
  }
}
// Ejecutar la función para renombrar las fotografías con la fecha de captura
renombrarFotos(fecha_nacimiento);
```

Recuerda que este código es un script JScript que puede ser ejecutado en Windows. Para hacerlo, guarda el script con extensión ".js" (por ejemplo, "renombrar_fotos.js") y luego haz doble clic sobre el archivo para ejecutarlo. El script abrirá un cuadro de diálogo para que selecciones la carpeta donde están las fotografías que deseas renombrar. Las fotografías serán renombradas con el formato "nombre (edad)", usando la fecha de captura de la fotografía y la fecha de nacimiento fija que proporcionaste.

Comment: Muchas, muchas gracias @5n10m, tanto por la respuesta como por la rapidez. He probado el script de 2 formas, copiándolo directamente en el botón y desde un archivo *.js pero no funciona. Cuando me aparece la ventana "Seleccione la carpeta con las fotografías" y selecciono la respectiva carpeta, me aparece el mensaje "Los nombres de archivos de origen y destino son idénticos". Es como si en la carpeta seleccionada, se intentaran copiar las fotos con el mismo nombre, o sea, sin llegar a incluirles la edad

Comment: No será mejor, que al presionar el botón no se pida seleccionar ninguna carpeta, sino que se renombren solo los archivos que se encuentren actualmente seleccionados?

Comment: Puedes modificar el script al gusto. Sólo es una idea de concepto.

Comment: Muchas gracias una vez más, voy a ver qué puedo hacer, no sé nada de programación

Comment: Hola @5n10m, podrías, por favor, modificar tu código para que no me pida una carpeta con fotos, sino que intente actuar directamente sobre las fotos seleccionadas, lo restante intentaré hacerlo yo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

```js
   // creamos una función que recibe os parámetros adecuados
function edad( nombre, fechaNacimiento, fechaFoto, extension ) {

       // instanciamos los objetos "Date" respetando el formato "yyyy-MM-dd"
    var fechaInicio = new Date( fechaNacimiento ).getTime();
    var fechaFin = new Date( fechaFoto).getTime();   

       // creamos un objeto "Date" con la diferencia entre fechas
    let diff = new Date( fechaFin - fechaInicio );
    
       // le restamos "1970" años a la fecha
    diff.setFullYear( diff.getFullYear() - 1970 );
    
       //  creamos la cadena que devolverá la función
    let edad = nombre + " ( " + diff.getFullYear() + "a " + diff.getMonth() + "m " + diff.getDate() + "d )." + extension;
   
    return edad;
}

console.log( edad( "Ester", '2016-07-12', '2017-08-19', "jpg" ));
```

PD: seguramente te preguntarás porque de la resta de "1970" años, yo también, no jaja, un objeto "Date" es en realidad el número de segundos transcurridos desde que empezó el año "1970", por lo que la resta entre dos fechas, siempre te da la diferencia más "1970" años, espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Entendí @Marcos Puente, ese asunto "Tiempo" es medio confuso, ja ja

Comment: Acabé de ejecutar el script pero me dá error en la línea 9, posición 9 **let diff = new Date( fechaFin - fechaInicio );**, qué podrá ser?

Comment: Copie todo el código, tal y como lo escribiste, directamente en el botón, en modo JScript. Hablando de fechas, no introduje ninguna fecha y en el script tampoco vi ninguna fecha fija, que sería la fecha de nacimiento de Ester. Ese código que me escribiste es un código completo o solo un fragmento? Disculpa molestar tanto

Comment: Entonces en esa línea que me especificas **2016-07-12** correspondería a la fecha de nacimiento?, y ojalá y supiera hacer ese renombrado que me indicas, ja ja, de todas formas mil veces gracias!

Comment: Sí, he leído con atención todos los datos y comentarios que has agregado pero es que no sé mucho de programación. Realmente no tengo ningún código, ni el de renombrar, lo comenté así al formular la pregunta, que no sabía nada del tema. Para obtener la fecha de captura de la foto podríamos hacerlo por medio de **{datetaken}**, un metadato

Comment: Si escribo la siguiente instrucción en un botón: **Rename IGNOREEXT PATTERN * TO "* ({datetaken|D#dd-MM-yy})"** le inserta a la foto su fecha de captura en formato dd-MM-aa, sin la hora de captura, que es excluida con los caracteres **D#**

Comment: que lenguaje usas? (de paso borrá los comentarios anteriores, porque tienen un máximo, sino los borran todos).

Comment: Esas funciones creo que son funciones estándar del propio Explorador de archivos (Directory Opus), que te las mostré para que vieras que con **{datetaken}** se puede obtener las fecha de captura de las fotos. El código podrías seguir desarrollándolo en JScript, él corre perfectamente bien también

Comment: Dio error en la primera línea **Function OnClick( ByRef ClickData )**, y aunque no sé mucho de programación, por lo que veo, ese código si está cerca de dar en el centro de la diana, muchas gracias una vez más, pero ya por hoy está bien, descansa, otro día si puedes darme otra mano te lo agradezco de corazón, fuerte abrazo!

Comment: Hola @Marce Puente, entré en el forum oficial del programa, y me dijeron que el script no estaba funcionando porque había mezclado funciones estándares (Rename IGNOREEXT PATTERN...) con funciones JScript y VBScript. Por lo que no para ahora por ser fin de semana, pero más adelante, si pudieras, echarle un vistazo a tu último código, te lo agradeceré siempre, buen final de semana!

Comment: Hola @Marce Puente, disculpa por continuar interrumpiendo tu final de semana, pero solo quería decirte que incluí 4 enlaces al final de la pregunta, cuyas informaciones tal vez faciliten tu trabajo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para la lectura de la fecha de la imagen (metadatos) he conseguido una especie de librería llamada [**Exif**](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/4956/the-exifworks-class), como indica la descripción de esta *"ExifWorks es una clase 100% escrita y gestionada en **VB.NET**"*, el cual para obtener la fecha puedes usar `DateTimeOriginal`, no estoy muy claro como podría ejecutarse este programa pero podria ser algo asi:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim SaveLoc As String
    SaveLoc = My.Settings.SaveLocation

    Dim Bitmap As String
    Bitmap = SaveLoc + "\Test\" + "1decfabd90e2355eac81b3f9735e10e3.jpg"

    '' libreria Exif
    Dim EX As New ExifWorks(bitmap)
    Dim dateStr As String = EX.DateTimeOriginal
    EX.GetBitmap.Save(SaveLoc + "\Test\" + "fecha-edad.jpg")

End Sub
```

Esto como un simple ejemplo, pero todavía le falta agregarle el formato de la fecha, para eso podría usar las funciones `ASP VB` para el manejo de las fechas como `CDate` y `Datediff`. Los ejemplos principales usan un formato como el siguiente:

```
fechaDesde="31-Jan-09 00:00:00"
fechaHasta="31-Jan-10 23:59:00"
```

Entonces con la ayuda de `Datediff` puedes declarar 3 variables usando diferentes parámetros como `d`, `y`, `m` y luego las pasas a `CDate` para convertir en una fecha valida y lo usas para escribir el archivo de imagen generado.

Mas información:

- https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_vbscript_functions.asp
- https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/function-procedures

Comment: Muchas gracias @user327285 por el aporte, voy a estudiarlo e intentar armar el código. De todas formas, coloqué, al final de la pregunta, 4 link relacionados al tema, del propio desarrollador del programa. Muchas gracias una vez más!